# Update to Search API 1.18 causes HTML to be displayed as plaintext

Tags: search, security

A security update to Search API (7.x-1.18) adds new sanitation as a security measure.  Great!  ..Except it now causes my custom field to be displayed as plaintext instead of HTML.

Here is the relevant code that was added to Search API:

```
/**
 * Sanitizes field values returned from the server.
 *
 * @param array $values
 *   The field values, as returned from the server. See
 *   SearchApiQueryInterface::execute() for documentation on the structure.
 *
 * @return array
 *   An associative array of field IDs mapped to their sanitized values (scalar
 *   or array-valued).
 */
function search_api_get_sanitized_field_values(array $values) {
  // Sanitize the field values returned from the server. Usually we use
  // check_plain(), but this can be overridden by setting the field value to
  // an array with "#value" and "#sanitize_callback" keys.
  foreach ($values as $field_id => $field_value) {
    if (is_array($field_value)
      && isset($field_value['#sanitize_callback'])
      && ($field_value['#sanitize_callback'] === FALSE || is_callable($field_value['#sanitize_callback']))
      && array_key_exists('#value', $field_value)
    ) {
      $sanitize_callback = $field_value['#sanitize_callback'];
      $field_value = $field_value['#value'];
    }
    else {
      $sanitize_callback = 'check_plain';
    }
    if ($sanitize_callback !== FALSE) {
      $field_value = search_api_sanitize_field_value($field_value, $sanitize_callback);
    }
    $values[$field_id] = $field_value;
  }
  return $values;
}
```

**Question**

Because it says

```
  // Sanitize the field values returned from the server. Usually we use
  // check_plain(), but this can be overridden by setting the field value to
  // an array with "#value" and "#sanitize_callback" keys.
```

I know I need to set the field value to an array with `#value` (my custom HTML) and `#sanitize_callback` keys, but *where* do I set this, and what do I use for `#sanitize_callback`?

**My Custom Code**

I'm using a callback to generate my field with custom HTML:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains SearchApiAlterAddViewedEntity.
 */

/**
 * Search API data alteration callback that adds an URL field for all items.
 */
class MySearchAlterAddUsercacheEn extends SearchApiAbstractAlterCallback {

  /**
   * Only support indexes containing entities.
   *
   * @see SearchApiAlterCallbackInterface::supportsIndex()
   */
  public function supportsIndex(SearchApiIndex $index) {
    return (bool) $index->getEntityType();
  }

  public function alterItems(array &$items) {
    // Prevent session information from being saved while indexing.
    drupal_save_session(FALSE);

    // Force the current user to anonymous to prevent access bypass in search
    // indexes.
    $original_user = $GLOBALS['user'];
    $GLOBALS['user'] = drupal_anonymous_user();

    foreach ($items as &$item) {
      // Since we can't really know what happens in entity_view() and render(),
      // we use try/catch. This will at least prevent some errors, even though
      // it's no protection against fatal errors and the like.
      try {
        $render = user_view($item, 'ensearch', 'en-US');
        $text = render($render);
        if (!$text) {
          $item->search_api_viewed_en = NULL;
          continue;
        }
        $item->search_api_viewed_en = $text;
      }
      catch (Exception $e) {
        $item->search_api_viewed_en = NULL;
      }
    }

    // Restore the user.
    $GLOBALS['user'] = $original_user;
    drupal_save_session(TRUE);
  }

  public function propertyInfo() {
    return array(
      'search_api_viewed_en' => array(
        'label' => t('Entity (en-US) HTML output'),
        'description' => t('The whole HTML content of the entity when viewed.'),
        'type' => 'text',
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is described in [this d.o issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2710745).

```
function MODULE_search_api_results_alter(array &$results, SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
  if (!empty($results['results'])) {
    foreach ($results['results'] as $id => $result) {
      if (!empty($result['fields']['search_api_viewed'])) {
        $results['results'][$id]['fields']['search_api_viewed'] = array(
          '#value' => $result['fields']['search_api_viewed'],
          '#sanitize_callback' => FALSE,
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`check_plain()` encodes special characters that has special meaning in HTML (such as < and &) into plain text entities (i.e. < and & respectively) that will make these be rendered literally (not interpreted as HTML) when that string that is then displayed as part of a page with HTML-markup. 
`filter_xss()` filters an HTML string to prevent cross-site-scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities.

In other words, filter_xss() takes care of security, while not plain-texting HTML.

I propose you to patch the Search API function with 'filter_xss' as a callback instead of 'check_plain', create an issue on drupal.org and explan that case.